# How to set the default tint color in mupdf

Tags: pdf, mupdf

According to the manual, the option seems to be `-C`, however it seems not working. How can I set default tint color?

The command I use is like this:

```
mupdf myfile.pdf -C FF0000
```

No color changed.

Answer (score 0):

Pass options before the filename like this:

```
mupdf -C FF0000 myfile.pdf
```

Comment: error: "-C" file not found

Comment: Maybe `mupdf` is a shell alias or function that messes with the command-line options. What's the output of `type mupdf`?